# Fetching market value of my cryprocurrency from Waves Exchange

Tags: wavesplatform

Our cryptocurrency trades at Waves platform against BTC. 
How can i fetch the market value of my cryptocurrency using my PHP program ? Any API available for the same ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one library for PHP development: https://github.com/deemru/WavesKit
Or you can use public API of Waves.Exchange matcher: https://matcher.waves.exchange/

Example of request URL to get the last price and other info in USDN/WAVES pair:
https://matcher.waves.exchange/matcher/orderbook/DG2xFkPdDwKUoBkzGAhQtLpSGzfXLiCYPEzeKH2Ad24p/WAVES/status

Comment: Thanks for the details. But this will return price in Waves. I want price in USD. Even if i get the current market value of Waves in USD, it is fine. I can then calculate my asset price in USD